# If $x$ and $y$ are rational numbers such that : $(x+y)+(x-2y)\sqrt {2}=2x-y+(x-y-1)\sqrt {6}$

Tags: arithmetic, real-numbers, rational-numbers

> If $x$ and $y$ are rational numbers such that : $$(x+y)+(x-2y)\sqrt {2}=2x-y+(x-y-1)\sqrt {6}$$ then which of the following is true?

A) $\;x=1$, $y=1$

B) $\;x=2$, $y=1$

C) $\;x=5$, $y=1$

D) $\;x$ and $y$ can take infinitely many values.

Given:
$$(x+y)+(x-2y)\sqrt {2} = (2x-y)+(x-y-1)\sqrt {6}$$
$$x+y-2x+y+(x-2y) \sqrt {2}=(x-y-1)\sqrt {6}$$
$$(x-2y)\sqrt {2} - (x-2y)=(x-y-1)\sqrt {6}$$
$$(x-2y)(\sqrt {2} -1)=(x-y-1)\sqrt {6}$$
Only the values at option B satisfies the equation. I just did that by hit and trial. Is there any elaboration on that?

Comment: D is correct, since we have just 1equation but 2varibles

Comment: @JordanLawson Is right. The equation given in the question is essentially a straight line and there should be infinite rational values of $x$ and $y$ that satisfy the equation, one of them being $(2,1)$ . So shouldn't the answer be $B)$ and $D)$ ?

Comment: @JordanLawson  D is not correct.  The requirements that $x$ and $y$ are rational restrict the possible answers on a straight line to just $(x,y)=(2,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

**And why is this down voted?**

$$2y-x = \sqrt{2}\Big(2y-x+\sqrt{3}(x-y-1)\Big)\;\;\;\;\;\;/^2$$

$${(2y-x)^2\over 2}+x-2y = \sqrt{3}(x-y-1)$$
If $x-y-1\ne 0$ we have
$$\sqrt {3}= \underbrace{{(2y-x)^2\over 2}+x-2y\over x-y-1}_{\in\mathbb{Q}}$$

which is impossible. So $y=x-1$ and $${(2y-x)^2\over 2}+x-2y=0$$

Solve this system and you are done.

Edit: So $(x-2)^2+2x-4x+4=0$ so $x^2-6x+8=0$ So $x=2$ (and $y=1$) or $x=4$ and ($y=3$). So the answer is $\boxed{B)}$

Comment: How did you write the second step? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$\sqrt{2}$
and
$\sqrt{6}$
are linearly independent, their coefficients must be zero.

Therefore
$0 = x-2y = x-y-1$

so $x=2, y=1$.

They threw in

$x+y=2x-y$

for the fun of it.